# How to find the correct air filter for my car?

Tags: honda, civic, part-identification, air-filter

I am trying to replace my both Cabin and Engine Air filter. The problem is, not sure how to find the match for it.

I check the existing air filters and this is what it says.

**Cabin Air Filter**

> > 5092 14 0762 >PET, PP< 76AA-T0GO-A000-M1

**Engine Air Filter**

> > > PP, TD30< ACE63

**car model**: 2012 honda civic

Comment: Seems like a shopping question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/honda,2012,civic,1.8l+l4,1501248,fuel+&+air,air+filter,6192), the parts are as follows:

**Engine Air Filter** OEM Part #: 17220R1AA01

- WIX 49031
- Hasting AF1481
- Denso 1433662
- ACDelco A3632C
- Beck/Arnley 0421825
- Mahle/clevite LX3444
- FRAM CA11113

**Cabin Air Filter** OEM Part #'s: 80292SDAA01, 80292SDCA01, 80292SECA01, 80292SWAA01

- TYC 800003P
- ATP CF40
- Denso 4532026
- Hastings AFC1244
- Beck/Arnley 0422023
- WIX 24815
- Mahle/Clevite LA216